# Aws mqtt connection using cognito credential provider in android

Tags: android, mqtt

I am trying to my app connect with mqtt broker using cognito credentials provider. When I was trying to connect to mqtt broker..app saying identity poolId not found.

```
  CognitoUserSession cognitoUserSession = AppHelper.getCurrSession();

                String idToken = cognitoUserSession.getIdToken().getJWTToken();

                Map<String,String> logins = new HashMap<String, String>();
                logins.put("cognito-idp.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/XXXX_XXXX", idToken);

                CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "ap-south-1:XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX", // Identity pool ID
                        Regions.AP_SOUTH_1 // Region
                );
                credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);

                AmazonCognitoIdentity cognitoIdentity = new AmazonCognitoIdentityClient(credentialsProvider);
                GetIdRequest getIdReq = new GetIdRequest();
                getIdReq.setLogins(logins); //or if you have already set provider logins just use credentialsProvider.getLogins()
                getIdReq.setIdentityPoolId(credentialsProvider.getIdentityPoolId());
                GetIdResult getIdRes = cognitoIdentity.getId(getIdReq);

                AttachPrincipalPolicyRequest attachPolicyReq = new AttachPrincipalPolicyRequest(); //in docs it called AttachPolicyRequest but it`s wrong
                attachPolicyReq.setPolicyName(AWS_IOT_POLICY_NAME); //name of your IOTAWS policy
                attachPolicyReq.setPrincipal(getIdRes.getIdentityId());
                new AWSIotClient(credentialsProvider).attachPrincipalPolicy(attachPolicyReq);

                mqttManager.connect(credentialsProvider, new AWSIotMqttClientStatusCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(final AWSIotMqttClientStatus status, Throwable throwable) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                txtStatus.setText(status.toString());
                            }
                        });


                    }
                });

            }catch(final AmazonClientException e){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"exception : "+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Exception : "+e);

            }
```

Log file:

```
 com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.ResourceNotFoundException: IdentityPool 'ap-south-1:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX' not found. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: bdd3c355-79b0-48f3-8a18-716fa17c44ce)
```

Can any one guide me how to resolve this one. What was the wrong in my code.

Thanks in 
Advance.

Answer (score 0):

As your log shows, you did not set the **Cognito Identity Pool ID** and the **Region** (where your Identity pool is) in your android app. You can find them under **sample code** of your identity pool in AWS federated identity dashboard.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I have set cognito identity pool I'd and region in my app. You can seen the CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider method.

Comment: The log that you posted shows some how they are wrong. Did you also correctly set your **user pool id** for **logins** (i.e. do you get idToken from your user pool)?
I would suggest to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61110436/use-cognito-login-instead-of-certificates-to-authenticate-and-subscribe-to-aws-i/61642810#61642810).

Comment: Thanks @Keivan, I can get idToken from user pool. I am following below link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44244375/aws-iot-android-application-over-mqtt-throws-mqttexception-0-java-io-ioexcep